# Secondary Use case scenario

Tags: use-case

I know how to write primary use case scenarios for documenting the use case diagrams. But i couldn't find a way to include secondary scenarios. Is there a format, or way to include it? I googled everywhere but there's no mention about secondary use case scenarios. any help would be appreciated. I just want a format or example.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you referring to "Alternate Flows"?

Comment: I'm not sure, it says "rewrite primary scenario to include secondary scenarios"

Comment: Well, you must know what you intend to write; no? How does it apply? How does the original document look? Have you googled for documenting (not modeling) a use case?

Comment: Tried everywhere, seems like to me it means something else. I cannot verify it. but i will keep looking.

Comment: Google for "Cockburn writing effective use cases"

Comment: Is your question homework in a class? Guidance from the Open Unified Process (OpenUP) on use cases states the main scenario and alternate flows. http://www.utm.mx/~caff/doc/OpenUPWeb/openup/guidances/guidelines/detail_ucs_and_scenarios_6BC56BB7.html